# Runing plugin project from another java project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a plugin project project say pluginProject in workspace workspace1 and a java project say javaProject in workspace workspace2. Now my requirement is that I want run a pluginProject's test from a class inside javaProject. How can this be achieved?

Detailed description along with snippet is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by 'pluginProject's test'?

Comment: I created a junit test (containing main plug-in code) which when I run as Junit Plugin Test, it works/executed. Otherwise for all other possible options like Run as Java Application, Junit Test, it fails by throwing error.

Comment: Eclipse plugins can only be used as plugins, they cannot be used by normal Java programs

Comment: when I run the same piece of code in main() and run it as java application, it throws an error - 
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workspace is closed.
 at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace(ResourcesPlugin.java:340)
 at com.plugins.test01.main(test01.java:21)` But when the same lines inside a junit test are executed through junit plugin test then it works.

Comment: You can only use the Workspace in a plugin running in Eclipse, it is not possible to use it from a normal Java program.

Comment: I referring to a workspace which was created using Eclipse.

Comment: Yes but you cannot use `ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace` in an ordinary `main`, you can only use it in an Eclipse plugin which is running in Eclipse or an Eclipse RCP or headless application.

Comment: So you mean the way its working now is correct i.e. it ll run only as Junit Plug-in test and not as java appltn - Undstd. Nw my requirement is that I want to run this plug-in appltn thrgh code. I have a java proj (in same workspace) in which I want to execute this plug-in by giving a call to it. What i have done:

`Plugin-Proj:
1. Created a junit test - responsible to build a particular project
2. Created a test suite which consist of above test
3. Create Class consisting main() and runs test suite
4. Created runnable jar

Java-Proj:
1. Added the runnable jar
2. call to Main class(Need to do)`

Comment: Here, I am directly running the plug-in jar by double clicking on it. When I do so, a cmd pops up and vanishes with message as: `Error:
Incorrect commandline argument`

Where am I wrong? Is plug-in not executable outside the project?